# React: 'map' is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, truffle

I'm trying to create an app that add on a table the information inputted in a form to a table. But before using the smart contract I wanted to try doing it with only js by following a CodePen given previously by another user of SO (https://codepen.io/giumagnani/pen/BJMrzW?editors=0010).

But I get the following error:

> `TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`.

Here is the code:

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      orderCount: 0,
      OrderIDInput: null,
      numberOfUpdate: null,
      BarcodeInput: null,
      initiatingCounterparty: '0x0',
      ProductListInput: '',
      TemperatureMinimalInput: null,
      TemperatureMaximalInput: null,
      ExpirationDateInput: '',
      FinalDestinationInput: '',
      date: '',
      orders: []
    }

  };


  render() {
    if (!this.state.web3) {
      return <div>Loading Web3, accounts, and contracts...</div>;
    }
    const orders = this.orders;
    return (
      <div className="App">

        <div id="OrderListTable" class="List">
          <h2>Orders</h2>
          <table id="ShipmentList" class="Shipment_List">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th id="OC01" class="Column">OrderID</th>
                <th id="OC02" class="Column">Number of update</th>
                <th id="OC03" class="Column">Barcode</th>
                <th id="OC04" class="Column">Initial counterparty</th>
                <th id="OC05" class="Column">Product list</th>
                <th id="OC06" class="Column">Minimum temperature</th>
                <th id="OC07" class="Column">Maximum temperature</th>
                <th id="OC08" class="Column">Final destination</th>
                <th id="OC09" class="Column">Expiration date</th>
                <th id="OC10" class="Column">Date of modification</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              {orders.map(order => {
                return (
                  <tr>
                    <td>{order.OrderIDInput}</td>
                    <td>{order.numberOfUpdate}</td>
                    <td>{order.BarcodeInput}</td>
                    <td>{order.initiatingCounterparty}</td>
                    <td>{order.ProductListInput}</td>
                    <td>{order.TemperatureMinimalInput}</td>
                    <td>{order.TemperatureMaximalInput}</td>
                    <td>{order.FinalDestinationInput}</td>
                    <td>{order.ExpirationDateInput}</td>
                    <td>{order.date}</td>
                  </tr>
                );
              })}
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>

      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Can't reproduce

Comment: `const orders = this.state.orders` not `const orders = this.orders`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So close you are trying to put the orders property on the state into a variable but then you are setting it wrong.
So it should be;

```
  const orders = this.state.orders;
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing `state` when assigning  `const orders = this.orders;` it should be

```
 const orders = this.state.orders;
```

Answer (score 1):

Be sure you are passing an array. Backtrack the data which is supposed to be an array (the one that `map()` is being used on). `console.log` everywhere you can.